# Parsing a big json then multiple small jsons

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pseudocode

My english is not the best, but I will try to explain what I want. So, we have a big json which has a lot of data, now because the server cant show us all the data at the same time, there will be multiple links to small json inside this big json, like when there are 20 comment on a page, and after that there is a "Show more comments" button. My problem is that I dont know how to do this, how to request the smaller json, the parse it. Another question is how to parse a json which links at the end to another json, something like when requestiong a json from graph api and at the end it has

```
[paging] => stdClass Object
(  
    [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/$group_id$/feed?access_token=$valid_token$&__paging_token=$paging_token$&__previous=1
    [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/$group_id$/feed?access_token=$valid_token$&limit=25&until=1375310522&__paging_token=$paging_token$
)
```

When the link from the [next] is opened, it shows more post from that group, then again at its end there is a next link.
As for the first question, I have a bit longer example from the facebook graph api comments

```
[comments] => stdClass Object
(
[data] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 53575265890127
        [from] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Pop Dan
            [id] => 10000897827962
        )
    [message] => Random message
    [can_remove] => 1
    [created_time] => 2013-08-18T20:01:44+0000
    [like_count] => 0
    [user_likes] => 
    )
    ... more coments...
[paging] => stdClass Object
    (
        [cursors] => stdClass Object
        (
            [after] => NTM1ODIxODE5ODA2NTQ0
            [before] => NTM1NzUyNjU2NDgwMTI3
        )
        next] => https://graph.facebook.com/$group_id$_$post_id$/comments?access_token=$accestoken$&limit=25&after=NTM1ODIxODE5ODA2NTQ0
    )
)
```

There I want to continue parsing the json from the [next] and then print it in the same html page, without any breaks or anything between comments. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the details depend on the language you are using for querying graph api.

Json returned from graph api can consist of json arrays and json objects. Json objects can further have named value entities

If you are doing it in android then first of all you have to get the inner json object from the response first. you can do it in this way

```
GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
                        JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
```

Now to get an object from the json you can use

```
jso.getJSONObject("object_name");
```

and to get json array you can use

```
jso.getJSONArray("array_name")
```

other languages will have similar interfaces

For general understanding of json refer to this [**link**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Regarding your second question you should understand that next is just another query to the graph node but with different parameters. How the parameters can be set depends on the api but in Android you can pur parameters as follows

```
Bundle params=r.getParameters();
    params.putString("offset", ""+25);

r.setParameters(params);
```

r is the object of type Request

Comment: I know how to parse a json, but I dont know how to get and parse the other jsons linked in the first json. I am using php.